# (.BAT) Adding String to Clipboard

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, clipboard

I am looking for a solution i have been trying to research for a little while.

I am making a .bat program to use at my work for templates to be placed in a certification document. Trying to speed up the process of copying and pasting .

Currently i am using notepad, highlighting and CRTL+C / V to copy the template.

I have built a .bat program that will do it in a selection window (enter 1-8 ect ect)

The only problem i am having is i was wondering if i can place the template inside the scripting of the .bat, and it will copy it to the clipboard.

example of template (must have spaces and breaks):
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Processed OK:

Surface Hardness Tested HR:

Name
03/21/2015
Company

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

i know of the "clip" command, but i can only find ways to copy stuff from a .txt. document, and i would like to avoid having 8+ .txt documents for every template. (e.g: clip > temp1.txt)

So is there a way to copy a prefab'ed template from within the .bat

example:

```
if %TYPE%==1 goto temp1

:temp1
clip ???????
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure you can. You can create arbitrarily complex streams to be fed into the `clip` program, such as:

```
@echo off
(
    echo hello
    echo goodbye
) | clip
```

If you run a `cmd` file containing those commands, then open up a `notepad` document and use <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>, it will paste the text:

```
hello
goodbye
```

Just replace the two `echo` commands with whatever code you need to generate the template.

Comment: Thank you sir, this should work fine. The longer templates will take some time, but be well worth it.